# C#: как "импортировать" только отдельный метод класса?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Только начал изучать `C#` и резко почувствовал необходимость некоторых функций из `Python`.

Решил создать отдельную библиотеку и разместить туда все методы, чтобы использовать `print();` вместо `Console.WriteLine();` и т.п.

Добавил в проект еще один класс с реализацией метода `print()`, называется `PythonCS`.

**PythonCS.cs**

```
using System;

namespace TempApp
{
    public class PythonCS
    {
        public static void print(object text = null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(text);
        }
    }
}
```

Не могу понять, как "импортировать" только конкретную функцию, чтобы затем использовать `print();` в основном коде не так:

```
PythonCS.print();
```

А так:

```
print();
```

Грубо говоря мне нужно что-то вроде `from lib import func` из `Python`

Но при этом чтобы не приходилось импортировать каждый метод отдельно, то есть `from lib import *`

---

**Основной код:**

```
using System;

namespace TempApp
{
    class Program
    { 
        static void Main()
        {
            PythonCS.print();
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier

Comment: @tym32167, почему не ответом?

Comment: @Grundy лень оформлять :)

Comment: @tym32167 спасибо, мне помогло. Оформите, отмечу как решение :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`static` - модификатор

Директива `using static` указывает тип, доступ к статическим членам и вложенным типам которого можно получить, не указывая имя типа. Директива `using static` была представлена в C# версии 6.

Вы можете обращаться к статическим членам типа без необходимости квалификации доступа с помощью имени типа:

```
using static System.Console;
using static System.Math;
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        WriteLine(Sqrt(3*3 + 4*4));
    }
}
```

[Источник](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-directive#static-modifier)